# Google Maps Android API Samples Key not working?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm an Android/Java noob trying to get Google Maps Android API Samples to work with an emulator (Nexus 5X API 26) and Android Studio on my Macbook.

I copied the github repo for the samples and loaded it into Android Studio. Now, the project compiles and I have the app on the emulator, but the map doesn't seem to be loading in the fragment.

- I don't see any errors in the console.
- I have created my unrestricted GMaps API Key and updated it in the manifest file and the resource/debug google_maps_api.xml files.

This is the Activity in question.
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/BasicMapDemoActivity.java

I also set a breakpoint at onMapReady() and it does get hit. But the fragment is blank. How do I debug it further?

Answer (score 0):

Go to android manifest(sample project) find this line.

```
 <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

In values folder you will find `google_maps_api.xml` change the value of `google_maps_key` with your development google map key because in `google_maps_api.xml` it is clearly mentioned that

```
Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
    string in this file.

    Note: This resource is used for the debug build target. Update this file if you just want to run
    the demo app.
```

Check this link if you haven't created any project in google developer console https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/open-bidder/google-app-guide

[image: I think there is problem with your emulator because it is working in my AVD]

Comment: I have already taken care of the manifest file and the xml files like I mentioned in the post.

Comment: please check the above answer, it is working in my AVD

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it myself by switching from an emulator to a real phone.

Looks like some emulators don't come pre-loaded with Google Play services APK. That might have been the issue.